# Find the inverse, domain and range of $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-2x}}$

Tags: functions, inverse

The inverse I am getting is $f^{-1}(x)= \frac{1}{2x^{2}}$. The domain and range of $f(x)$ is $x<0$ , $y>0$. The domain and range of $f^{-1}(x)$ is $x>0$ , $y>0$ though.

What am I doing wrong? Is my inverse function incorrect?

Comment: you forgot to put  the -ve sign the $f^{-1}(x)= \frac{-1}{2x^{2}}$

Comment: Hmm... I thought squaring the negative radical expression on the bottom of the fraction would result in a positive sqrt (4x^2). Why is my math so off?

Comment: you should solve more problems.@user152810

Answer (score 0):

Starting for $x < 0$  with
$$
y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-2x}} > 0 \Rightarrow \\
y^2 = -\frac{1}{2x} > 0 \Rightarrow \\
x = - \frac{1}{2y^2} < 0
$$
we get the inverse function
$$
f(x) = -\frac{1}{2x^2}
$$
with the domain $(0, \infty)$ and range $(0, -\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks! If you square both sides of the equation like you did in your second line, wouldn't the right side of the equation be 1/sqrt(4x^2) leading to 1/2x without the negative?

Comment: No, $\sqrt{-2x} \sqrt{-2x} = \sqrt{(-2x)^2} = -2x$, note that $-2x$ is a positive number, because $x$ is a negative number.